# $1 substitution for Apache's RewriteRule doesn't return the first matched expression

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I've read everywhere that pattern substitution in Apache's Rewrite Engine works as expected for regular expressions, so I tried:

**.htaccess**:
`RewriteRule (.*) index.php?route=$1`

But for a request to `domain.com/some/url` in the get var ***route*** I get `index.php` instead of `some/url`

In the http var `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` I get `route=some/url`
But in `QUERY_STRING` I get `route=index.php`

What could be wrong here?

PS: `$0` also returns `index.php`
If I use `RewriteRule . index.php?route=$1`, I get route=`i`, whatever the request URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1` is working as expected but problem is your use of this pattern:

```
(.*)
```

which matches anything. Your rewrite rule **actually loops and runs twice** because you don't have any `RewriteCond` to precent looping.

1. First it runs for URI=`some/url` and URI becomes `index.php` while `$1` becomes `some/url`
2. Second time it runs for URI=`index.php` and `$1` becomes `index.php`

You can use this rule to fix this behavior:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

OR if you want to rewrite existing files and directories to `index.php` then use:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php$).*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will rewrite everything except `index.php` to `index.php`.

Comment: Thanks!
I get the use for [L,QSA], but what about the RewriteConds? are they for this specific problem? Because I actually do want that even if requests match existing file or directory names they still be directed to index.php

Comment: ok check rule in my updated answer to rewrite all files/directories also.

Comment: Thanks, but just adding the flags made it work, even without excluding `index.php` either with the Conditions or with the regex